# How to get all products where a title begins with specific string in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have those products:

```
Name1 SECONDNAME 1 
Name1 SECONDNAME 2
Name1 SECONDNAME something
Name1 SECONDNAME something 5
Name2 SECONDNAME 1
Name2 SECONDNAME 2
Name2 SECONDNAME something
Name2 SECONDNAME something 5
```

I want to list them like this:

```
    $query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
        'title' => 'Name1 SECONDNAME *'
    ) );
    $products = $query->get_products();
```

Comment: Can you print the output you get?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that you can call where you need it. Add it in your functions.php file

```
function get_product_ids_by_title($search_string) {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
    $post_type = 'product';

    $query = $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT ID
        FROM $table_name
        WHERE post_type = %s
        AND post_title LIKE %s",
        $post_type,
        $wpdb->esc_like($search_string) . '%'
    );

    $product_ids = $wpdb->get_col($query);

    return $product_ids;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$search_string = 'your_search_string';
$product_ids = get_product_ids_by_title($search_string);

// Output the retrieved product IDs
foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) {
    echo $product_id . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Rather than `WC_Product_Query`, you could use `WP_Query` and the `sentence` parameter (tested):

```php
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    's'              => 'Name1 SECONDNAME ',
    'sentence'       => true,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $products = array_map( 'get_product', $query->posts );
}
```

Comment: 's' => 'Name1 SECONDNAME ' is matching everything that includes 'SECONDNAME' too

Comment: Sorry, updated answer.

Comment: Agh sorry, moving too fast. Tested and updated answer.